# Java Spark broadcast variable in separate file

Tags: java, apache-spark, broadcast

I need to create a broadcast variable in my driver program and use it in a class in a separate file.

For example I have this in the driver:

```
public static final Relation[] relations = {
     Test1.getRelationSigleton(),
     Test2.getRelationSigleton()
};
```

relationsBroadcast = ctx.broadcast(relations);

And in a map step I need to get this:

```
private Relation[] relations = relationsBroadcast.value();
```

The problem is that it can't compile because relationsBroadcast hasn't been declared in the scope of the new file.

My solution now is to have the map step in the same file as the driver, but it looks messy and I want to move it out.

Comment: Since relations is static, you can declare the broadcast in the piece of code where you are using it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @rhernando mentioned in a comment, the way to do this was to use the static reference to the variable from the main class.